# How to match typescript Record value with the key?

Tags: typescript, record

```
interface User {
  email: string;
  name: string;
}

const UserRecord = Record<keyof User, keyof User> {
  email: 'email',
  name: 'name',
};
```

My problem with the above code that it's not typesafe for the values, so I could even do:

```
const UserRecord = Record<keyof User, keyof User> {
  email: 'name',
  name: 'email',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
interface User {
  email: string;
  name: string;
}

const UserRecord: {
  [x in keyof User]: x
} = {
  email: 'email',
  name: 'name',
};
```